# Redirect to Subdomain after Sign In

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, subdomain, redirect

I am working on an multilatency application using Devise for authentication. The use of subdomains is critical for this build.

Currently my set up includes forcing the user to 'remember' their subdomain so that they can log in.

**Routes**

```
constraints(SubdomainPresent) do
  root 'users#index', as: :subdomain_root
  resources :users
  resources :accounts
end

devise_for :users
```

What I would like to achieve is something very similar to what takes place when my users first register whereby once they are saved, they are redirected to their subdomain to sign in (url structure reflects this) subdomain.example.com

**Account Controller**

```
if @account.valid?
  Apartment::Tenant.create(@account.subdomain)
  Apartment::Tenant.switch(@account.subdomain)
  @account.save

  format.html { redirect_to new_user_session_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain), notice: 'Account was successfully created.' }
```

I would like to have it so my users can sign in from any where on the site, non-subdomain location,  and have it redirect them to their correct dashbaord, and subdomain url structure

Answer (score 1):

You can override the **after_sign_up_path_for** Method and use it something like this:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     edit_user_registration_url(:subdomain => resource.subdomain)
  end
```

[Devise Guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-or-sign_up)

Comment: Just FYI, `redirect_to root_url(subdomain: 'new_customer')` works as well.